# asynchronous datagrid view c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, view, datagrid

People would like to ask you for help with the following situation.
I have a monitor where I check if certain machines are online. To make this process I have a script running on the machine feeding the database with the current time. Already on the monitor, I have an asynchronous check in Infinite loop to pick up the last updated time of the bank and update my Data Grid View. However I'm having some locking problems in this loop, someone could help follow my code

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (timerExec)
    {
        timerExec = false;
        selectStatusRobos();

    }
    //timer1.Enabled = false;
}

public async void selectStatusRobos()
{
    String Configuracao = "server=;user=midas_Client;password=;database=;port=3306";
    string query = "SELECT i.Usuario_meta, i.Nome_robo, i.Simbolo, i.Periodo, i.Status_op, i.Operacao, i.Hora_criacao, c.Id, i.Corretora FROM int00 AS i INNER JOIN cliente00 AS c ON i.Usuario_meta = c.Usuario_meta AND i.Corretora = c.Corretora";
    MySqlConnection conexao = new MySqlConnection(Configuracao);
    try
    {
        await conexao.OpenAsync();
        MySqlCommand COMANDO = new MySqlCommand(query, conexao);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter =  new MySqlDataAdapter(COMANDO);
        DataTable status = new DataTable();
        await adapter.FillAsync(status);
        bool flag_find = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            flag_find = false;
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Status"].Value = Properties.Resources.if_exclamation_red_46014;
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Operacao"].Value = Properties.Resources.if_op_null;
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Status_op_img"].Value = Properties.Resources.if_op_null;
            for (int b = 0; b < status.Rows.Count; b++)
            {

                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Id"].Value.ToString() == status.Rows[b]["Id"].ToString()
                    && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Usuario_meta"].Value.ToString() == status.Rows[b]["Usuario_meta"].ToString()
                    && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Corretora"].Value.ToString() == status.Rows[b]["Corretora"].ToString()
                    && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Nome_robo"].Value.ToString() == status.Rows[b]["Nome_robo"].ToString()
                    && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Simbolo"].Value.ToString() == status.Rows[b]["Simbolo"].ToString().Substring(0, 3)
                    && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Periodo"].Value.ToString() == status.Rows[b]["Periodo"].ToString())
                {
                    flag_find = true;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Status"].Value = Properties.Resources.if_tick_circle_frame_27247;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Hora_ultima"].Value = status.Rows[b]["Hora_criacao"].ToString();
                    if (status.Rows[b]["Operacao"].ToString() == "1") // Compra
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Operacao_img"].Value = Properties.Resources.if_Raise_32535_16;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Operacao"].Value = status.Rows[b]["Operacao"].ToString();
                    }
                    else if (status.Rows[b]["Operacao"].ToString() == "2") // Venda
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Operacao_img"].Value = Properties.Resources.if_Fall_32468_16;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Operacao"].Value = status.Rows[b]["Operacao"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Operacao_img"].Value = Properties.Resources.if_op_null;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Operacao"].Value = status.Rows[b]["Operacao"].ToString();
                    }

                    if (status.Rows[b]["Status_op"].ToString() == "2") // Off
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Status_op_img"].Value = Properties.Resources.if_power_off_10214;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Status_op"].Value = status.Rows[b]["Status_op"].ToString();
                    }
                    else if (status.Rows[b]["Status_op"].ToString() == "1") // On
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Status_op_img"].Value = Properties.Resources.if_power_on_10215;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Status_op"].Value = status.Rows[b]["Status_op"].ToString();
                    }
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Status"].Value = Properties.Resources.if_tick_circle_frame_27247;
                    //query = "DELETE FROM `int00` WHERE Usuario_meta = @usuario_meta AND Nome_robo = @nome_robo AND Simbolo = @simbolo  AND Periodo = @periodo";
                    //COMANDO.CommandText = query;
                    //COMANDO.Parameters.Clear();
                    //COMANDO.Parameters.Add("@usuario_meta", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = status.Rows[b]["Usuario_meta"].ToString();
                    //COMANDO.Parameters.Add("@nome_robo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = status.Rows[b]["Nome_robo"].ToString();
                    //COMANDO.Parameters.Add("@simbolo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = status.Rows[b]["Simbolo"].ToString();
                    //COMANDO.Parameters.Add("@periodo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = status.Rows[b]["Periodo"].ToString();
                    //COMANDO.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //break;
                }
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Hora_ultima"].Value != null)
                {
                    DateTime t = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Hora_ultima"].Value.ToString());

                    // if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Hora_ultima"].Value.ToString() != status.Rows[b]["Hora_criacao"].ToString())
                    if (flag_find)
                    {
                        DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;
                        DateTime t2 = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-30);
                        System.TimeSpan diff2 = t1.Subtract(t);
                        if (diff2.TotalSeconds >= 15 && diff2.TotalSeconds <= 45)
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Status"].Value = Properties.Resources.if_58_62715;
                        }
                        else if (diff2.TotalSeconds < 15 && diff2.TotalSeconds >= 0)
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Status"].Value = Properties.Resources.if_tick_circle_frame_27247;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Status"].Value = Properties.Resources.if_exclamation_red_46014;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }

        //frm = this.MdiParent as frmPrincipal;
        //SendMessage send = new SendMessage(frm.SetLabel);
        //send(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm :ss") + " - Dados Atualizados...", null, null);
        conexao.Close();
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {

        frm = this.MdiParent as frmPrincipal;
        SendMessage send = new SendMessage(frm.SetLabel);
        send(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm :ss") + " - Tempo limite excedido na seleção", ex.Message + ex.StackTrace, Properties.Resources.if_Close_Icon_Dark_1398917, 15000);
        //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace, "Detalhes Exception");
        timerExec = true;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
        frm = this.MdiParent as frmPrincipal;
        SendMessage send = new SendMessage(frm.SetLabel);
        send(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm :ss") + " - Tempo limite excedido na seleção", ex.Message + ex.StackTrace, Properties.Resources.if_Close_Icon_Dark_1398917, 15000);
        timerExec = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        frm = this.MdiParent as frmPrincipal;
        SendMessage send = new SendMessage(frm.SetLabel);
        send(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm :ss") + " - Dados Atualizados...", null, null, 15000);
        conexao.Close();
        timerExec = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: "having some locking problems in this loop" I guess as long as you don't describe your problem in detail, people here will not be inclined to read through all the dumped code (that lacks even a single comment to explain the workings) and try to understand it and figure out what the problem might be here.

Comment: @Igor Viela  Welcome to StackOverflow! Consider upvoting answers to your other questions, and the best one, you should be marking as 'accepted answer' with the green checkmark. It'll help ensure you get good answers to future questions!

Comment: @Member2017 the other question the he posted is the same as this one but only in portuguese